# Change to another activity when item Material Drawer is clicked

Tags: java, android, drawer, materialdrawer

I am trying to switch to another activity when the item in Material Drawer is clicked. I am using Material Drawer (com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:2.9.8) in this application. The problem is when I try to switch to another activity with clicking item, its always drive to default case (switch case).

Here are my code:
**MainFeed.java**

```
package com.example.anggit.myacademic.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import com.example.anggit.myacademic.R;
import com.example.anggit.myacademic.Tab.MyAdapter;
import com.example.anggit.myacademic.Tab.SlidingTabLayout;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;

public class MainFeed extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    //Drawer
    private Drawer.Result navigationDrawerLeft;
    private AccountHeader.Result headerNavigationLeft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_feed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mViewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vp_tabs);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));

        mSlidingTabLayout=(SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.stl_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_view, R.id.tv_tab);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        //=========================================================================================
        headerNavigationLeft = new AccountHeader().withActivity(this).withCompactStyle(false).withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState).withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.userprofilebg).addProfiles(
                new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Anggit Prayogo").withEmail("anggitprayogo@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nopicture))
        ).build();

        navigationDrawerLeft = new Drawer()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withDisplayBelowToolbar(false)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .withDrawerGravity(Gravity.LEFT)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withAccountHeader(headerNavigationLeft)
                .withSelectedItem(0)
                .build();

        navigationDrawerLeft.addItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Profil").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_face_black_24dp)));
        navigationDrawerLeft.addItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Setting").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_settings_24dp)));
        navigationDrawerLeft.addItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Logout").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logout)));

        navigationDrawerLeft.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                Intent intent = null;
                switch (drawerItem.getIdentifier()) {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(MainFeed.this, EditProfil.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d("Test","Default");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

thanks for helping:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 navigationDrawerLeft.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainFeed.this, EditProfil.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("Test","Default");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

the index of the list always starts with 0

```
 navigationDrawerLeft.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (drawerItem.getIdentifier()) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(MainFeed.this, EditProfil.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("Test","Default");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

use 0 instead of 1 in your switch case

Comment: its still drive to default case, i've changed it to  case 0. but still the same